# How to tell the path of a file in a .php document?

Tags: php

I have the following line:

```
<a href="posts/?p=page_archiveName">
```

I have a file called "page_home.php", it has some links, the links files are in the "posts" folder, I do not know why, but when I click on the link it is not showing the file.

But when I delete the "posts /" path of the line, and I throw the file from the posts folder, putting it in the same folder as the page_home.php, everything works normally.

I disagree that it is because of this script just below, it was not me who created it, so I do not know what the problem is.

```
<?php

$pagina = empty($_GET['p']) ? 'home' : $_GET['p'];

switch ($pagina):
case 'contato':
    $titulo = 'Contato | BizarroNEWS';
    $keywords = '';
    $descricao = 'descricao contato';
    break;

case 'privacidade':
    $titulo = 'Privacidade | BizarroNEWS';
    $keywords = '';
    $descricao = 'descricao privacidade';
    break;

case 'ultimasnoticias':
    $titulo = 'Últimas Notícias | BizarroNEWS';
    $keywords = '';
    $descricao = 'descricao noticias';
    break;

case 'archiveName':
    $titulo = '';
    $keywords = '';
    $descricao = '';
    break;

default:
    $titulo = 'BizarroNEWS | Home';
    $pagina = 'home';
    $keywords = '';
    $descricao = 'descricao home';
endswitch;
```

[erro_print_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vrLY.jpg)

Comment: `page_archiveName` wont match `archiveName`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yea, so what can i do?

Comment: Replace `?p=page_archiveName` with `?p=archiveName`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i did it before, but it is not working.

Comment: If `posts` if just a folder, then no page will load unless you have setup your `.htaccess` to redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to load a file, you *generally* have 3 options:

1. Link to the file directly
   `/path/to/file.txt`
2. Include the file within another php file
   `<?php include "/path/to/file.txt";`
3. Redirect with `.htaccess` using `RewriteEngine`

**Option 2** seems to be the one you're looking for.

I recommend you:

1. Create a file named `posts.php`
2. Add your above script into the file
3. Change your links from `posts/?p=archiveName` to `posts.php?p=archiveName` (don't move any  files)
4. Add this line to the bottom of `posts.php`:

   `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/posts/".$_GET["p"].".php";`

Comment: "2. Add your above script into the file", which one? my PHP script? Anyway i made some tests, i put my html script above posts.php, and your script on the bottom, my index.php are loading the link to the file posts.php and showing some texts,imgs..etc. But its not pointing to my folder "posts". I created "posts.php" on main dir. And i tried to put my PHP script above posts.php but showed an error on the browser, you can see a print screen on my question.

Comment: Yes your php script. I've just updated step 4 which should resolve your error. The error is simply stating that the path is incorrect.

Comment: Also make sure that `home.php` does exist within the posts folder